# Tidyeval: How to pass a list with quoted elements to a nested function without user quoting?

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

Say I have two functions and I want to nest `a` within `b`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

a <- function(var, values){
  filter(iris, {{var}} %in% values)
}

a(Species, "virginica") %>% head()

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
2          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
3          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
4          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
5          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
6          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

`b` calls `a`, but uses the dot-dot-dot `...` for some other things. It has a list argument that is passed to `a`:

```
b <- function(l, ...){
  eval_tidy(expr(a(!!! l)))
}

b(l = list(var = quo(Species), values = "virginica")) %>% head() # works if user passes quosure
```

Can I pass a list of arguments to `b` to be evaluated in `a` when some of the elements need to be quoted? So the call to `b` would look like the following:

```
b(l = list(var = Species, values = "virginica")) # does not work
```

I have tried the following, but it seems I need to split-splice one more time or something:

```
b <- function(l, ...){
  l <- enquos(l)
  qq_show(a(!!! l))
}

b(l = list(var = Species, values = "virginica"))

# a(^list(var = Species, values = "virginica"))
```

Other attempts result in premature evaluation of `Species` and therefore the error: `object 'Species' not found`.

Comment: You need to take the list of expressions by value (no `enquo()`) and require your users to use _external quoting_. See https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html#sec:external-quoting

Comment: Ah reading again, you had already figured out that the user had to defuse the expressions themself (in this case by using `quo()`). I see no other reasonable way. Are you sure you need to structure the interface in this way? It seems weird to me to collect heterogeneous arguments in a list like that.

Comment: @LionelHenry Generally, I have a quoting function nested in a quoting function. I'm not sure how to pass a subset of arguments from the parent to the nested function when the `...` is unavailable for use. The other issue is that, like many functions, the user might specify some subset of arguments for the nested function, not necessarily all of them -- which is why I was trying to split-slice a list.

Comment: ok I _think_ I understand the problem, I have added an anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper function that collects arguments for `a()`. This helper can defuse `var` with `enquo()` so the user does not have to use `quo()`.

```
a <- function(var, values) {
  filter(iris, {{ var }} %in% values)
}

a_opts <- function(var, values) {
  list(var = enquo(var), values = values)
}
```

Then `b()` expects the user to pass a list of arguments presumably created with `a_opts()`. But how do we pass these arguments to `a()`? We can't use `!!!` directly because splicing is only enabled in `...` (see [dynamic dots](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dyn-dots.html)) and `a()` doesn't take `...`.

One solution is to use `do.call()`. Another solution idiomatic to rlang is to enable `!!!` explicitly with `inject()`:

```
b <- function(l) {
  inject(a(!!!l))
}
```

Example usage:

```
a_opts(Species, "virginica") %>%
  b() %>%
  head()
```